# Does modpagespeed split CSS files like Blesscss.com to avoid IE's 4095 selector limit?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, mod-pagespeed

IE has a selector limit of 4095 in a single CSS file.

When modpagespeed combines all CSS files, how do i set it up to use the blesscss.com functionality to split css files yet still retain the hash'd filenames so I can keep long expires?

Comment: I don't believe the selector limit is taken into account. You can blacklist specific files in your config and minify and compress them manually. Having said that, that's a whole lotta selectors - are you sure you can't split the file into more independent components? I can't imagine that all of your pages use all of the selectors. That by itself might be a better performance optimization.

Comment: @igrigorik thanks for the insight on modpagespeed. So is there no solution to this problem? Splitting up the css files is not an option, the aim is to reduce http requests, load all the css in one go so it is cached in the browser

Comment: I would either open an issue with the developers or add the functionality to the source and build yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be support being added to 1.7

See https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=658 and https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=793